# What does & means in function declaration in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Sometimes I see that kind of declaration:

```
void f(int& a,...){
 }
```

What does & mean? Because * is pointer, without * is object, so what is that?

Comment: It's a reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: Look at the link. In C, using a pointer was known as passing by reference, but C++ actually has references, which are sometimes a much better fit. No extra syntax, and some semantics differences as well.

Comment: In "C", "&" is merely the [addressof operator](https://www.techcrashcourse.com/2015/12/pointer-address-of-and-value-of-operator-in-c.html).  C++, as Chris said, also has "references": https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/.  Your C++ function signature is the latter.